# How to perform stratifiedShuffleSplit in GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Can I run StraitifiedShuffleSplit inside GridSearchCV without having to instantiate it first as "ss" in case of my code.

```
ss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=3, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf_us, param_grid = {parameter: num_range},cv=ss)
```

Comment: Judging by the documentation if you specify an integer GridSearchCV already uses stratified KFold in some cases: "For integer/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is either binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used. In all other cases, KFold is used.". http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

Comment: @KRKirov  yes that is true but what about StrarifeidshuffleSplit ?

Comment: They are  more or less equivalent when it comes to stratification. I think if you want the finer control the test_size provides, then you probably can't avoid instantiating the StratifiedShuffleSplit first.

Comment: @KRKirov do you have any idea what test size does it implement if we specific cv with 5 for example ?

Comment: @KRKirov  also in case of instantiating what will be the CV ? Is it the same as n_splits now ?

Comment: Please see the example in this page to see how the different parameters affect the splitting of the data.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit

Comment: @KRKirov can you please add it as answer so I can choose it thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are building a classifier and are only concerned with keeping the same label balance in each fold as in the complete data set, you can avoid instantiating StratifiedShuffleSplit by specifying the number of folds in GridSearchCV, e.g. cv=5.

According to the documentation: “For integer/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is either binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used. In all other cases, KFold is used.”
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

However, if you want to have a finer control over the data splitting then you can’t avoid instantiating StratifiedShuffleSplit. Please see the example in this page to understand how the test_size parameter affects the splitting: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit .